# can i delete some bones making a metarig before i generate the rig?

Tags: rigging, bones, rigify

I'm making a metarig and there are a lot of face bones which are nice but some of them I really don't want to use. others, however, would be really nice to have on my rig. can I delete some of the face bones while keeping others?

Edit: these are the only bones i have kept from the original 3 face rig layers [image]